# Suggested edit from question author to their own question goes to review queue

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

The only previous questions I could find about this here on Meta Stack Exchange turned out to be an edit by the question author through a different account (same name and avatar, but different userid).

However, in this case the **same userid** has posted a question, then later suggested an edit, which I then approved in the edit review queue.

Is this intended behaviour? I was surprised to see a user's edit to their own post needing to be approved. Is there a rep requirement for editing your own post?

Here is the [revision history](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/posts/2441/revisions) showing that the userids are identical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens often with unregistered accounts. They post a question, lose the cookie and get locked out of the account, then suggest an edit to the very question *they* wrote. Later on, their unregistered account gets merged into their registered account, and it looks like they suggested an edit to their own post.

Comment: Would this apply in the short time between proposing an edit and me picking it up in the review queue (about 2 hours)?

Comment: Well, if the suggested edit has already been created, then merging their account will not affect anything. It doesn't auto-approve things upon merge. The edit *was* proposed before their accounts were merged though, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't realise merging could be done so quickly.