# Should I accept an anonymous edit on a post by an unregistered author who claims to be locked out of their original account?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, user-accounts, unregistered-users

[I saw this review in the queue:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/225656)

[image]

If the anonymous user is indeed DBChronos, this edit seems totally acceptable. However, if not, this could conflict with the author's intent.

[DBChronos is indeed an unregistered user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/271608/dbchronos), so that matches up. However, I have no way to actually verify the identity of the anonymous user.

Should I approve this edit anyways? Should I reject it because I can't verify the user's identity? [Should I wait for them to merge their account with a registered account, then accept the edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279314/suggested-edit-from-question-author-to-their-own-question-goes-to-review-queue)

<sup>Sidenote: I skipped it in the queue.</sup>

Comment: Here's a few cross-site related meta questions on [superuser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12690/should-i-perform-a-duck-test-when-reviewing-suggested-edits), [unix.se](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/what-do-i-do-when-a-user-edits-their-question-with-another-account), and [ubuntu.se](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3563/what-to-do-when-an-anonymous-user-insists-they-are-the-op-for-an-edit). The consensus across all three is to allow it if it isn't obvious vandalism.

Comment: @n8te Seems good enough for me to be an answer... do you just not do answers though?

Comment: I can write it as an answer if you want. I just went with a comment at the time since it's almost a link-only answer.

Comment: @n8te I'd be honored to be your first answer! Pasting some relevant content from the body of accepted/highly voted answers on those answers seems fine to me, along with your own opinion if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators on Super User, Unix & Linux, and Ask Ubuntu have weighed in on this topic and the consensus across all three is to allow it if it's not obvious vandalism.

From [unix.meta.stackexchange](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/what-do-i-do-when-a-user-edits-their-question-with-another-account):

> This generally happens because they posted the question on an
>   unregistered account and then later registered one when they realized
>   they would need to follow-up on comments. I have yet to come across a
>   case where somebody makes a fake account with the same name to
>   impersonate another user, so you can probably assume it's the same
>   user and approve it, as long as the edit looks to actually be useful.
>
> --Michael Mrozek

From [meta.askubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3563/what-to-do-when-an-anonymous-user-insists-they-are-the-op-for-an-edit):

> I approve if they aren't obviously a vandal. We can't do a IP check,
>   or anything like that so its a little difficult, but again, if it
>   isn't vandalizing (and adds value to the question) then by all means,
>   approve it.
>
> --jrg

See also this question on [meta.superuser.com](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12690/should-i-perform-a-duck-test-when-reviewing-suggested-edits)

Comment: Worth pointing out, one should leave a comment, that indicates they can recover the account with a little effort (5 minutes worth of effort).